# findAll() method does not work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to remove all of the tag from the link that i got from crawling.

here is the code

```
request = urllib2.Request("http://sport.detik.com/sepakbola/")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response)

   for a in soup.findAll('a'):
   if 'http://sport.detik.com/sepakbola/read/' in a['href']:
            urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', a)
```

unfortunately, it does not work, and it says expected string or buffer in findAll(), is it like the output from for each is not a string? any help will be appriciated

thanks

Comment: Could you fix your indentation?

Comment: @skzryzg done it :).is that enough?

Comment: yea, thanks.  I assumed that's what you intended, but if you DID have indentation problems in your code, then a similar error message would be generated and I wanted to be sure before I made an assumption

Comment: but unfortunately I have to go to work, so if it is not answered later, I will take a look when I get a chance.  good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a` in your loop is not a string, it's a dictionary (or, specifically, a BeautifulSoup.Tag). In your `if` statement you correctly get the `href` string from the dictionary to compare with, but when matching the regex you're not.

Simply using the string `a['href']` instead of the dictionary `a` in the regex match will fix your runtime error;

```
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
  if 'http://sport.detik.com/sepakbola/read/' in a['href']:
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', a['href'])
```

Answer (score 2):

Indentation of the code is not correct here. Please fix it. Change the last line as:

```
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', a['href'])
```

`a` here is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` type, not a string. So you are getting the error. Change it to `a['href']` which is a `<type 'str'>`.

Comment: How is this different from the answer I posted an hour earlier, except that you got 2 upvotes? :)